# I have a problem with the library d3.js for xAxis which doesn't appear?

Tags: d3.js

I have hit a problem with the module d3.js,
I try to display a graph with data and it works well, but please I don't understand
why sometimes the displaying of my y-axis appear and, others times, it disappears.
At each time, I get my curves, just the y-axis which didn't appear

I am looking for a solution on many website but any doesnt work,
but I notice that, in function of data I furnished in my code,  it appears

```
 
    /*//let letialo=document.getElementsByName('maletiableP');
//console.log(letialo);

// Récupérez l'élément HTML qui contient la letiable
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  let projectsDat = document.querySelector('p[id="projects"]');
  //console.log("projectsDat :");
  //console.log(projectsDat);
  //onsole.log("projects 1:");
  //console.log(projects_test[0].projectKey);
})

// Set dimensions and margins for the chart
const margin = { top: 70, right: 30, bottom: 40, left: 80 };
const width = 1200 - margin.left - margin.right;
const height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

//console.log(projects)
//console.log(maletiablePartagee);

// Set up the x and y scales
const x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]);
const y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);

// Create the SVG element and append it to the chart container
const svg = d3
  .select("#chart-container")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left},${margin.top})`);

// create tooltip div
const tooltip = d3.select("body").append("div").attr("class", "tooltip");

// if you want to load data, please comment the dataset part
//load data from a file
//d3.csv("./csvFile/file.csv").then(function (data) {
//console.log(data);
//});

// Transformez le tableau projects en un format compatible avec votre dataset
const transformedData = [];

projects.forEach(project => {
  for ( const key in project) {
    let lastKey=null;
     
    if (key !== lastKey)
    {
      if (key !== 'projectKey') {
      const date = new Date(key);
      const value = project[key];
      transformedData.push({ date, value });
    }
  }
    else 
    {
      console.log("tu es bete");

    }
    lastKey=key;
  }
});
//sans trier les donnees (les dates) dans lordre croissant on 
//le tooltip ne fonctionne pas
transformedData.sort((a, b) => a.date - b.date);


// Create a fake dataset
const dataset =[
  { date: new Date("2022-01-01"), value: 2 },
  { date: new Date("2022-02-01"), value: 5 },
  { date: new Date("2022-03-01"), value: 7 },
  { date: new Date("2022-04-01"), value: 3 },
  { date: new Date("2022-05-01"), value: 2 },
  { date: new Date("2022-06-01"), value: 15 },
  { date: new Date("2022-07-01"), value: 10 },
  { date: new Date("2022-08-01"), value: 9 },
  { date: new Date("2022-09-01"), value: 8 },
  { date: new Date("2022-10-01"), value: 3 },
  { date: new Date("2022-11-01"), value: 7 },
  { date: new Date("2022-12-01"), value: 3 },

  { date: new Date("2023-06-01"), value: 2 },
  { date: new Date("2023-07-01"), value: 3 },
  { date: new Date("2023-08-01"), value: 4 }];

 /*const dataset=[
  { date: new Date("2023-09-01"), value: 280 },
  { date: new Date("2023-10-01"), value: 660 },
  { date: new Date("2023-11-01"), value: 770 },
  { date: new Date("2023-12-01"), value: 355 },
  { date: new Date("2023-12-01"), value: 845 },

  { date: new Date("2024-06-01"), value: 223 },
  { date: new Date("2024-07-01"), value: 334 },
  { date: new Date("2024-08-01"), value: 456 },
  { date: new Date("2024-09-01"), value: 280 },
  { date: new Date("2024-10-01"), value: 660 },
  { date: new Date("2024-11-01"), value: 770 },
  { date: new Date("2024-12-01"), value: 355 },
  { date: new Date("2024-12-01"), value: 845 },
];*/

// Define the x and y domains
x.domain(d3.extent(dataset, (d) => d.date));
y.domain([0, d3.max(dataset, (d) => d.value)]);


// Add the x-axis
svg
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", `translate(0,${height})`)
  .style("font-size", "14px")
  .call(d3.axisBottom(x)
      .tickValues(x.ticks(d3.timeMonth.every(Math.floor(dataset.legnth / 11))))
      .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%b %Y")))
  .call((g) => g.select(".domain").remove())
  .selectAll(".tick line")
  .style("stroke-opacity", 0);
svg.selectAll(".tick text").attr("fill", "#777");

// Add the y-axis
svg
  .append("g")
  .style("font-size", "14px")
  .call(d3.axisLeft(y)
      
      .ticks((d3.max(dataset, (d) => d.value) - 150) / 40)
      
      .tickSize(0)
      .tickPadding(10)
  )
  .call((g) => g.select(".domain").remove())
  .selectAll(".tick text")
  .style("fill", "#777")
  .style("visibility", (d, i, nodes) => {
    if (i === 0) {
      return "hidden";
    } else {
      return "visible";
    }
  });

// Add vertical gridlines
svg
  .selectAll("xGrid")
  .data(x.ticks().slice(1))
  .join("line")
  .attr("x1", (d) => x(d))
  .attr("x2", (d) => x(d))
  .attr("y1", 0)
  .attr("y2", height)
  .attr("stroke", "#e0e0e0")
  .attr("stroke-width", .5);

svg
  .selectAll("yGrid")
  .data(y.ticks((d3.max(dataset, (d) => d.value) - 150) / 40).slice(1))
  .join("line")
  .attr("x1", 0)
  .attr("x2", width)
  .attr("y1", (d) => y(d))
  .attr("y2", (d) => y(d))
  .attr("stroke", "#e0e0e0")
  .attr("stroke-width", .5);

// Create the line generator
const line = d3
  .line()
  .x((d) => x(d.date))
  .y((d) => y(d.value));

// Add the line path to the SVG element
svg
  .append("path")
  .datum(dataset)
  .attr("fill", "none")
  .attr("stroke", "steelblue")
  .attr("stroke-width", 1)
  .attr("d", line);

// Adding tooltip to Curves.pug --Interactivite

// Add a circle element
const circle = svg
  .append("circle")
  .attr("r", 0)
  .attr("fill", "steelblue")
  .style("stroke", "white")
  .attr("opacity", .7)
  .style("pointer-events", "none");
// create a listening rectangle
const listeningRect = svg
  .append("rect")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height);

// create the mouse move function
listeningRect.on("mousemove", function (event) {
  const [xCoord] = d3.pointer(event, this);
  const bisectDate = d3.bisector((d) => d.date).left;
  const x0 = x.invert(xCoord);
  const i = bisectDate(dataset, x0, 1);
  const d0 = dataset[i - 1];
  const d1 = dataset[i];
  const d = x0 - d0.date > d1.date - x0 ? d1 : d0;
  const xPos = x(d.date);
  const yPos = y(d.value);

  // Update the circle position
  circle.attr("cx", xPos).attr("cy", yPos);

  // Add transition for the circle radius

  circle.transition().duration(50).attr("r", 5);

  // add in  our tooltip
  const options = { day: "numeric", month: "numeric", year: "numeric" }; //formatage de la date

  tooltip
    .style("display", "block")
    .style("left", `${xPos + 100}px`)
    .style("top", `${yPos + 50}px`)
    // formater en anglais  -Month/Day/Year il faut inserer 'en-EN'
    //formater en francais  -Day/Month/Year il faut inserer 'fr-FR'
    //formatage en millier  -(d.value / 1000).toFixed(0) parameter of .toFixed() 0 auncun chiffre apres la virgule
    //formatage en centaine  -(d.value / 100).toFixed(1); parameter of .toFixed() 1 un chiffre apres la virgule
    //formatage en dizaine  -(d.value / 10).toFixed(0) parameter of .toFixed() 0 auncun chiffre apres la virgule
    //formatage en unite  -(d.value / 1).toFixed(0) parameter of .toFixed() 0 auncun chiffre apres la virgule
    .html(
      `<strong>Date:</strong> ${d.date.toLocaleDateString(
        "fr-FR",
        options
      )}<br><strong>Num_of_Problems:</strong> ${d.value !== undefined ? (d.value / 1).toFixed(0) : "N/A"
      }`
    );
});
// listening rectangle mouse leave function
listeningRect.on("mouseleave", function () {
  circle.transition().duration(50).attr("r", 0);

  tooltip.style("display", "none");
});
// // Add Y-axis label
svg
  .append("text")
  .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
  .attr("y", 0 - margin.left)
  .attr("x", 0 - height / 2)
  .attr("dy", "1em")
  .style("text-anchor", "middle")
  .style("font-size", "14px")
  .style("fill", "#777")
  .style("font-family", "sans-serif")
  .text("Number of problems");

// // Add the chart title
svg
  .append("text")
  .attr("class", "chart-title")
  .attr("x", margin.left - 115)
  .attr("y", margin.top - 100)
  .style("font-size", "24px")
  //.style("font-weight", "bold")
  .style("font-family", "sans-serif")
  .text("Curves");

// // Add the source credit
svg
  .append("text")
  .attr("class", "source-credit")
  .attr("x", width - 1125)
  .attr("y", height + margin.bottom - 3)
  .style("font-size", "9px")
  .style("font-family", "sans-serif")
  //a changer en fonction dou sont prises les donnees
  .text("Source: https://bitbucket");*/
```